# make the program automatically go to background

Tags: iphone, ios6

I want to click on a button to make my program into the background. How would I do this?

If it used to jailbreak the phone，

Comment: It is not possible. Only home button can be used to do this and apple wont give access to that.

Comment: Play horrifying screeching music. Users will hit the home button for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the following anwsers

1. [Send App to Background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970221/send-app-to-background-process)
2. [Suspend the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360846/suspend-the-application)

**Don’t Quit Programmatically**

Never quit an iOS application programmatically because people tend to interpret this as a crash. However, if external circumstances prevent your application from functioning as intended, you need to tell your users about the situation and explain what they can do about it. Depending on how severe the application malfunction is, you have two choices.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean programmatically "minimize" the app (closing it while leaving it open in multitasking), I don't believe there's a way to do so using a public API.